# Difficulty with Gaussian Elimination involving a,b coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I have the system matrix as follows:

{1   2   2   1

1   a   3   3

1   11  a   b}

I am attempting to row reduce this matrix, but am having difficulty in this process, particularly with Row 3. I come to

{1   2   2   1

0   a-2   1   2

0   9   a-2  b-1}

but now I cannot see how to resolve the 9 in the third row to a zero.

My goal in all this is to determine what a must be (or must not be) in order for the system to have a unique solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while since I last opened my LA book, but I think it's something like this, right?

Replace `a - 2` by x and `b` by y because it simplifies the whole thing.

```
0 9 x y
```

Now divide the third row by 9.

```
0 1 (x / 9) (y / 9)
```

Then multiply it with x (or `a - 2`).

```
0 x (x ^ 2 / 9) (x * y / 9)
```

Now you can subtract the second row.

```
0 0 (x ^ 2 / 9 - 1) (x * y / 9 - 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect. Can't believe I couldn't get there!